# Angular material2 dynamically generate columns

Tags: javascript, json, angular, angular-material2

I am using angular material ng-table and wanto to generate columns dynamically.
Following example contains html template. This is working example of "statically" defined table template. I want to replace all columnd definitions with something like code in comments.

```
<md-table #table [dataSource]="dataSource">
<ng-container cdkColumnDef="userId">
    <md-header-cell *cdkHeaderCellDef> ID </md-header-cell>
    <md-cell *cdkCellDef="let row"> {{row['userId']}} </md-cell>
  </ng-container>

  <ng-container cdkColumnDef="progress">
    <md-header-cell *cdkHeaderCellDef> Progress </md-header-cell>
    <md-cell *cdkCellDef="let row"> {{row['progress']}}% </md-cell>
  </ng-container>

  <ng-container cdkColumnDef="userName">
    <md-header-cell *cdkHeaderCellDef> Name </md-header-cell>
    <md-cell *cdkCellDef="let row"> {{row['userName']}} </md-cell>
  </ng-container>

  <ng-container cdkColumnDef="color">
    <md-header-cell *cdkHeaderCellDef>Color</md-header-cell>
    <md-cell *cdkCellDef="let row" [style.color]="row.color"> {{row['color']}} </md-cell>
  </ng-container>

  <md-header-row *cdkHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></md-header-row>
  <md-row *cdkRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;"></md-row>

<!-- <ng-container
  *ngFor='let column of tableOptions.columnDefs'
  cdkColumnDef='column.columnDef'>
  <md-header-cell *cdkHeaderCellDef> {{column.headName}} </md-header-cell>
  <md-cell *cdkCellDef="let row"> {{row[column.columnDef]}} </md-cell>
</ng-container> -->
```

columnDefs json looks like this:

```
columnDefs: [
    {
      columnDef: 'userId',
      headName: 'ID'
    },
    {
      columnDef: 'userName',
      headName: 'Name'
    },
    {
      columnDef: 'progress',
      headName: 'Progress'
    },
    {
      columnDef: 'color',
      headName: 'Color'
    }
  ]
```

Variable `displayedColumns` from header is as array `["userId", "userName", "progress", "color"]` which generation is based on `columnDefs` json

When I try using *ngFor, I get this error:

```
    TableComponent.html:24 
ERROR Error: cdk-table: Could not find column with id "userId".
    at getTableUnknownColumnError (cdk.es5.js:1780)
    at cdk.es5.js:2111
    at Array.map (<anonymous>)
    at MdTable.webpackJsonp.../../../cdk/@angular/cdk.es5.js.CdkTable._getHeaderCellTemplatesForRow (cdk.es5.js:2108)
    at MdTable.webpackJsonp.../../../cdk/@angular/cdk.es5.js.CdkTable._renderHeaderRow (cdk.es5.js:2016)
    at SafeSubscriber._next (cdk.es5.js:1952)
    at SafeSubscriber.webpackJsonp.../../../../rxjs/Subscriber.js.SafeSubscriber.__tryOrUnsub (Subscriber.js:238)
    at SafeSubscriber.webpackJsonp.../../../../rxjs/Subscriber.js.SafeSubscriber.next (Subscriber.js:185)
    at Subscriber.webpackJsonp.../../../../rxjs/Subscriber.js.Subscriber._next (Subscriber.js:125)
    at Subscriber.webpackJsonp.../../../../rxjs/Subscriber.js.Subscriber.next (Subscriber.js:89)
```

Is it possible to generate columns dynamically?

EDIT:

Plunker [example](https://plnkr.co/edit/9Wnme3fAEOdfSTGfyvF0?p=preview)

Comment: I found this https://github.com/angular/material2/pull/5545 ... it does not seems that it is possible in current version :/

Comment: the issue is resolved but its not been released yet, we will have to wait i guess.. see this for ref : https://github.com/angular/material2/issues/6159

Comment: plunker added (look into console for error)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you made mistake when were passing `cdkColumnDef` input to directive

```
cdkColumnDef='column.columnDef'
```

it means that cdkColumnDef will get `'column.columnDef'` string as value.

If i were you i would write it as:

```html
[cdkColumnDef]="column.columnDef"
```

or the following options are also available for you:

```html
cdkColumnDef="{{column.columnDef}}"
```

or

```html
bind-cdkColumnDef="column.columnDef"
```

[**Plunker Example**](https://plnkr.co/edit/D3d2VFSKaeQKoT1Zf0MK?p=preview)